# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

$\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ does not exist.

I can explain limit goes infinity, but how can show that, let $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=L$ and find a argument for L does not exist?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: First write the negation of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of "the limit is $L$", and this negation is what we desire. Then select $\epsilon=1$, and prove that this is an appropriate selection for "$\exists \epsilon>0$" in your negation (which will appear if you write it correctly.)

Comment: is it enough for epsilon=1 then for x in (0,1/(1+L)^2), f(x)>L+1?

Comment: Please do not post the same [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683514/epsilon-delta-proof-for-lim-x-to-0-dfrac1-sqrtx-does-not-exist) twice.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = L < \infty$$
so that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x| < \delta$ implies $\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt x} - L\right| < \epsilon$. Fix an $\epsilon > 0$ and the corresponding $\delta > 0$.

Now, $|x| < \delta$ implies $\frac{1}{\sqrt x} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{\delta}}$. By the triangle inequality, for all $x$ satisfying $|x| < \delta$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \le \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt x} - L\right| + |L| \le |L| + \epsilon < \infty$$
To find a contradiction, we shall pick some $x_0 > 0$ such that $x_0 < \delta$ but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0}} > |L| + \epsilon$. The choice
$$x_0 = \frac{1}{2} \min \left\{\delta, \frac{1}{(|L| + \epsilon)^2} \right\}$$
works. I leave it to you to see how.